# C# How to add members to <dynamic> array (JSON)

Tags: c#, json

I have created a `dynamic` object in C# by deserializing a JSON file. One of the fields inside the dynamic structure is an array of strings. How can I add a member to this array?

```cs
var complexObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("JsonSampleFile");
```

How to do something like this?

```
complexObject.member.submemberArray.add(...);
```

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>()` will deserialize a JSON array to the type [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm). That means you can use the [`Add`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Add.htm) method (notice, with an uppercase A):

```
complexObject.member.submemberArray.Add(...);
```

That's assuming your JSON looked something like this:

```
{
    member:
    {
        submemberArray: [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```